# Add a count of new questions on each tag since last visit in "Watched Tags" list

Tags: feature-request, tag-watching, custom-filters

On Stack Overflow (and other Stack Exchange sites), we can create custom filters by adding tags one wants to watch.

Would it be possible to add a count of new questions since the last visit to each respective tag in the watched tag list?